# a simple interactive matplotlib plot is not showed in jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I try to plot interactively a simple plot through jupyterlab. Here is the code I use to do so:

```
%matplotlib widget
plt.figure()
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, running that code produces the following output:

```
Canvas(toolbar=Toolbar(toolitems=[('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'), ('Back', 'Back to previous …
```

which seems to indicate that something is wrong with the rendering.

I followed the instructions for installing all the dependencies according other posts and documentation but it did not help. Here is what I installed:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipympl
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
conda install -c conda-forge widgetsnbextension
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
jupyter labextension install jupyter-matplotlib
```

Here is some info about the versions of my different packages:

```
python: 3.6.7
ipympl: 0.5.3
jupyter-lab: 2.0.1
jupyterlab-extension: 2.0.1
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.13.0
ipykernel        : 5.1.4
jupyter client   : 6.0.0
jupyter lab      : 2.0.1
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

would you have any idea ?

Comment: At your posting at the [ipympl github repo](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl/issues/201#issuecomment-598892845), I posted a suggestion for work-around to switch the notebook interfaces by editing the end of your URL from `lab` to `tree` to then try running your notebook in the classic interface.